# How do you get the app name when running Rails on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

This means app-name.heroku.com.

Note this is different from `Rails.application.class.parent_name`.

`Rails.application.class.parent_name` is defined in the application.

Working in Rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku actually sets a URL variable in the environment by default

```
app_name = ENV['URL'].split(".").first
```

Referenced here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars and http://ididitmyway.heroku.com/past/2010/11/9/sinatra_settings_and_configuration/

**update:** actually the URL variable might not be there by default, but you could always add an environment variable "app name" a priori, unless you were trying to avoid that approach all together.

**update 2:** indeed, the other, obvious but limiting approach, would be to grab the domain off the request variable, but this limits you to your controller. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object

Comment: I checked the config and there is no variable with app-name in it. Yes, setting a config is one approach.

Comment: this does not always work, because you could have used a different spelling for your app when you checked it in.. e.g. test-app instead of test_app

Answer (score 14):

The solution with `ENV['URL']` will only work during requests.

So if you need to know the app id outside a request, you's set a config variable like this

```
heroku config:add APP_NAME=<myappname> --app <myappname>
```

And enable [lab feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) that allows you to use them during compile

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

And now I have my app name available here:

```
ENV["APP_NAME"] # '<myappname>'
```

This is handy if you want to load different config file (say with oauth credentials) based on the app's name or id.

Comment: Maybe check your heroku gem version or install heroku toolbelt. Or check out the docs / contact heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/labs Be sure to share what helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
Rails.application.config.session_options[:key].sub(/^_/,'').sub(/_session/,'')
=> "test-app"
```

that's the name of the Rails app, as it was spelled when you did 'rails new app-name'

Using this, you could do this:

```
class << Rails.application
  def name
    Rails.application.config.session_options[:key].sub(/^_/,'').sub(/_session/,'')
  end
end

Rails.application.name
=> 'test-app'
```

Comment: Actually, that's the name of the cookie

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in different environments in each app per [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments), you could just set a variable in `staging.rb` or `production.rb`.