# How to get Heroku app name/URL from inside the app

Tags: heroku

I'm working on a registration agent for http://www.dif.io to enable tracking of apps deployed on Heroku. I'm missing some pieces of information for the deployed app. The registration agent is a script (usually written in the app native language) which is designed to be executed after deployment (heroku run for example or automaticaly via some post deploy hook if any).

How do I get the application name, URL and some UUID identifier from inside the app, preferably from some ENV variables? I need it to be portable between languages.

I explored a sample Python application and all of the above info is missing. There are only couple more ENV variables related to Python. The dyno hostname however looks like an UUID.

I could use something like this but without the user/password requirements:
https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/technical/reference/app-info

Please point me to the correct docs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488396/how-do-you-get-the-app-name-when-running-rails-on-heroku/7488495#7488495

Answer (score 55):

The command `app:info` no longer seems to be a `heroku` command but just `info` will do the same thing so:

```
heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2
```

or to set the variable

```
heroku config:set HEROKU_URL=$(heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2)
```

Comment: Although this is incredibly useful, I discovered it does not work from within the console. Which is kind of strange, because it seems like the app should know some basic environment info about itself.

Comment: At some point, Heroku changed `web_url` to `web-url`. So `heroku info -s | grep web-url | cut -d= -f2` will do the trick today.

Comment: Looks like you should avoid setting `HEROKU_*` named env vars due to high risk of internal conflicts on Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

Comment: I think it's heroku apps:info (with an "s")

Answer (score 32):

Dyno Metadata was introduced December 2015. It’s currently a labs feature which must be enabled first.

> Dyno metadata gives the dyno easy access to information about the app and environment. Examples of available dyno metadata include details about the release, dyno size, application name as well as the unique identifier for the particular running dyne.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

Comment: Currently dyno metadata does not contain app hostname

Comment: @timelf123 By March 2016, it does. (Or at least the documentation mentions it, I haven't actually tried it.)

Comment: Yes, the app name is listed as HEROKU_APP_NAME. However I wish there was a way to enable this from an app.json configuration.

Comment: Enabled on my instance and only HEROKU_DYNO_ID is available.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can add labs features to Heroku CI built apps?

Comment: For what it's worth, and to my above comment - if you're looking to get this information within Heroku CI test apps you need to set HEROKU_UAT to enabled for the test environment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-uat-via-3rd-party-providers. The documentation is kind of oddly split up over this.

Answer (score 19):

There's a labs add-on that came out in Aug 2016 which puts all of these in your environment:

```
~ $ env
HEROKU_APP_ID:                   9daa2797-e49b-4624-932f-ec3f9688e3da
HEROKU_APP_NAME:                 example-app
HEROKU_DYNO_ID:                  1vac4117-c29f-4312-521e-ba4d8638c1ac
HEROKU_RELEASE_CREATED_AT:       2015-04-02T18:00:42Z
HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION:          v42
HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT:              2c3a0b24069af49b3de35b8e8c26765c1dba9ff0
HEROKU_SLUG_DESCRIPTION:         Deploy 2c3a0b2
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

Comment: Enabled on my instance and only HEROKU_DYNO_ID is available.

Comment: @WillJones same here.

Answer (score 11):

Dynos themselves don't have any information about the application name or URL they are running, as far as I can tell. The [documentation on Dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#local-environment-variables) lists what local environment variables are set, but it's only has PORT and DYNO.

One workaround for that we use in [hubot](https://github.com/github/hubot) is to require the user to add a config like HEROKU_URL with the app hostname.

I've found that you can script most of this, by using `heroku app:info` with the `-s` flag for shell-friendly, with a little bit of grepping and cutting:

```
$ heroku apps:info -s  | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2
http://hubotio-campfire.herokuapp.com/
```

And to set HEROKU_URL from that:

```
$ heroku config:set HEROKU_URL=$(heroku apps:info -s  | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2)
```

Comment: Looks like you should avoid setting `HEROKU_*` named env vars due to high risk of internal conflicts on Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

Answer (score 8):

For those who came here, trying to find a way to get the app URL for the review apps in Heroku, we have two additional environment variables available:

1. HEROKU_BRANCH
2. HEROKU_APP_NAME

So to infer the URL is just: "http(s)://HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com"

Comment: would you be able to elaborate on how those environment variables were populated? I do not seem to have those variables in my heroku app?

Comment: They are maybe only available in the Heroku review apps. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#injected-environment-variables

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked for me for the app name only:

```
heroku info -s | grep git-url | sed 's#.\+\.com/\(.\+\)\.git$#\1#g'
```

My use case was to find the app name for use in a shell script which needed the app name specifically (not the domain name). YMMV

I used the `git-url` instead of `web-url` because the domain name can be overridden to something custom, but the app name will always remain mapped to the git url. If looking for the domain name, check one of the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

App name store in your url something like `appname.herokuapp.com`.

You can get it in many way e.g. `ENV['URL'].split(".").first` in python to get the first value form url when split by "." that represent your appname

Answer (score 2):

For me it was as simple as:

```
heroku info
```

```
heroku info
=== secure-inlet-07449
Addons:         heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
Auto Cert Mgmt: false
Dynos:          web: 1
Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/secure-inlet-07449.git
Owner:          some.one@example.com
Region:         us
Repo Size:      45 KB
Slug Size:      33 MB
Stack:          heroku-20
Web URL:        https://secure-inlet-07449.herokuapp.com/
```

The last line shows the app url: https://secure-inlet-07449.herokuapp.com/