# How to deploy a nuxt application that uses the @nuxtjs/apollo module, to heroku?

Tags: heroku, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-client

I am learning nuxtjs. I used it to build a todo app, implementing graphql on the backend (express) to set up my API.
When I wanted to implement apollo, I found that I had to use @nuxtjs/apollo module, it has a bunch of options to set in **nuxt.config.js**, but only one is required, so I just added the following code to my **nuxt.config.js** file:

```
modules: ["@nuxtjs/apollo"],
apollo: {
  clientConfigs: {
    default: {
      httpEndpoint: "http://localhost:3000/graphql"
    }
  }
},
```

It worked fine developing on my local machine. When I tried to deploy it to heroku I faced some problems.

I figured that the api calls are not done correctly, in my app's logs in heroku's dashboard I saw the following line:
`Error Network error: request to http://localhost:3000/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`
So I figured that I had to change the value of ***httpEndpoint*** in my ***nuxt.config.js*** file.
I also noticed that in heroku the host and port changes with every restart of the app, so I will get a uri like this: `http://172.18.254.242:24570/`

I know that I need to change the value of ***httpEndpoint*** in my ***nuxt.config.js*** file, but to what value exactly? I have no idea.

I searched a lot in the official docs but didn't find any solutions, I also tried every solution I could find on google and stackoverflow but didn't have any luck.

I want to know what value exactly should I pass in ***httpEndpoint*** to have my app working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the app name through `process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME` after enabling dyno metadata as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570579/how-to-get-heroku-app-name-url-from-inside-the-app). The port number should be available through `process.env.PORT`. So you may be able to build the url yourself:

```
https://${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com:${process.env.PORT}/graphql
```

Comment: After running the command suggested by the article, I got the following response: ```Enabling runtime-dyno-metadata for sleepy-inlet-14340... done```. I guessed all is ok so I edited the value in my code to: ```https://${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com:${process.env.PORT}/graphql```. Ater committing, pushing, and deploying. The app still didn't work, but I got the following on the browser's console: **Network error: https://undefined.herokuapp.com:undefined/graphql is not a valid URL.**. So the app isn't recognizing ```process.env``` variables for some reason. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I redeployed the app and now somehow it is partially fixed, the console now gives me: ```Network error: https://sleepy-inlet-14340.herokuapp.com:undefined/graphql is not a valid URL.```, so now it doesn't reconize only the **PORT** variable.

Comment: You might be able to [set the port yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097230/6024220).